# jquery mobile prevent default not working for phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

i wish to pass data via local-storage to another html page. sending data via the URL doesn't seem to work in phone gap

so i want to tap in the click event and run my data assignment function before the page changes

but the prevent default isnt working with the list view.

```
<ul class="content"  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
<li><a href="second.html"> <img src="image.jpg" /> to go to second page</a></li>
<li><a href="second.html"> <img src="image.jpg" /> to go to second page</a></li>
<li><a href="second.html"> <img src="image.jpg" /> to go to second page</a></li>
<li><a href="second.html"> <img src="image.jpg" /> to go to second page</a></li>
 </ul>
```

i have set up a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/kpv42yne/1/

my end goal is to get which list-view item was clicked and the values associated with it.
getting data via the URL doesn't seem to work.

the event.preventDefault() method is not working.. see the fiddle

Comment: Have you used localStorage.getItem("fileName"); on another page to get data.

Comment: yes i have..the i am not able to get a hold of the click event...it is being hijacked by jquery...i changed the location of my event registrations as well but no use..

Comment: i am using javascript templeting to generate the list..and after that i am registering the event which should work bcoz the DOM is already loaded and all the li tags exist but still facing problems

Comment: is the list dynamically generated?

Comment: yes the list is generated by a json file using mustache js

Comment: In this case, you need to delegate event to list items `$("static_parent").on("click", "dynamic_child", function(){});`.

Answer (score 0):

The *event.preventDefault()* is working fine. The problem is that your code is messed up. First of all this is not how you use jQuery selectors:

```
$(".content li,.content a")
```

I believe you are trying to do this:

```
$(".content li a")
```

I also have no idea what you are trying to do here:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','index', function(){   
    alert(2);    
    $(document).on('vmousedown click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Because a click on the `<a>` tag is what causes the page change, that's where you wan't to prevent the default behavior and save the value. So this is all you need:

```
$(".content li a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    localStorage.setItem("fileName", $("#path").val());
    console.log($("#path").val());

    window.location.href = "second.html";
});
```

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/9aa4nkx3/2/